# Gradle sync fails to get AWS Mobile Client library in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aws-mobilehub

I have a project loaded in Android Studio 3.0. Gradle sync works fine, and the project builds.

When I add `implementation 'com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+'` to my build.gradle (Module:app) file, right next to all the other dependencies that are already part of this fine project, gradle fails to find that dependency. Many of the existing project dependencies are under com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk-* and are being sync'ed just fine, for e.g. `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.+'` is fine.

So I double check that new project dependency actually exists, browsing http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-mobile-client shows it exists, I don't see a typo.

Looking at my build.gradle (Project: myProject), I see the following

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      google()
      jcenter()
  }
}
```

Yet when gradle syncs i get

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+:.

Could not resolve com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+:.
Required by:
project :app
No cached version of com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+: available for offline mode.`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncheck **"Offline Work"** in **Android Studio / File / Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Gradle**

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your dependency.

Use

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws.aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+'
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that typo, unfortunately gradle sync still fails to find this dependency, the only change is now the error message says "Could not resolve com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+." (without the typo)

Comment: Check the message. If it says: No cached version, you are working offline. You have to download the new dependency

Comment: Yes it did say that indeed. I didn't understand that though, I'm not offline, my internet works just fine. I don't want to have to download the jar's manually, I wouldn't even know where exactly to drop them in the gradle cache.
Thanks to your comment, I found the solution though, you put me on the right tracks. All i had to do was find the "work offline" setting and uncheck it.